# calculate a proportion of a quantity per ID

Tags: mysql

Here is my table. Type 0 is for `dislike`, type 1 is for `like`.

```
id | userid | postid | type
1  |   465  |  20    |  0
2  |   465  |  21    |  1
3  |   466  |  20    |  1
4  |   466  |  21    |  0
5  |   467  |  20    |  1
6  |   467  |  21    |  0
```

Now, my queries are

```
$sql = $bdd->query('SELECT COUNT(id) AS cntLikes,  postid, type FROM like_unlike WHERE type = 1 GROUP BY postid, type');
$sql = $bdd->query('SELECT COUNT(id) AS cntUnlikes,  postid, type FROM like_unlike WHERE type = 0 GROUP BY postid, type');
```

This displays to me:

```
postid(20) -> 1 like 
postid(21) -> 2 like1

postid(20) -> 2 dislikes
postid(21) -> 1 dislike
```

I want to calculate the % of `like` and display it for each `postid`.

```
$p = ($total_unlikes / ($total_unlikes+$total_likes)) * 100;
```

I've tried

```
$sql = $bdd->query("SELECT postid, COUNT(CASE type WHEN '1' THEN 1 END) AS cntLikes, COUNT(CASE type WHEN '0' THEN 1 END) AS cntunlikes from like_unlike GROUP BY postid, type");
    while ($donnees2 = $sql->fetch())  {
    $total_likes = $donnees2['cntLikes'];
    $total_unlikes = $donnees2['cntunlikes'];
    $ratio = ($total_unlikes / ($total_unlikes+$total_likes)) * 100;
    echo $donnees2['postid'],'  nb likes',$total_likes,' nb dislikes',$total_unlikes,'   percent',$p,'<br />';}
```

But it displays to me

```
postid(20)  -> nb likes 1 -> nb dislikes 0 -> percent 100
postid(20)  -> nb likes 0 -> nb dislikes 2 -> percent ->100
postid(21)  -> nb likes 2 -> nb dislikes 0 -> percent -> 100
postid(21)  -> nb likes 0 -> nb dislikes -> 1  percent ->100
```

The following is the end result that I want:

```
postid(20)  -> nb likes 1 -> nb dislikes 2 -> percent 33
postid(21)  -> nb likes 2 -> nb dislikes 1 -> percent ->66
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `type` from the `GROUP BY`, so that you don't get one group (and one row) for each type but one for both.